# Some apps throw GTK+ errors

Tags: firefox, gtk, gedit

System:  Ubuntu desktop 16.04.1 LTS

I get the following errors when running, gedit from a terminal command line:

> (gedit:5688): Gtk-WARNING **: GTK+ module libgail.so cannot be loaded.
>   GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same
>   process is not supported. Gtk-Message: Not loading module
>   "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please
>   try to not load it.

Firefox is the same except that it starts with (firefox:5711) .  If I don't already have firefox running, the error message adds:

> Couldn't get object: TypeError: Components.classes[cid] is undefined
>   Couldn't get string: closeAndStopPicking

The apps load, I just get the error message as well.

Is this fixable?  Is it something I should just ignore?

Comment: fill a bugreport https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs